# error deploying struts2 spring3 hibenate4 application - Schema export unsuccessful Access denied for user 'sa'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

I'm trying to create a struts2 application which uses Spring3 for the DI and hibernate4 to handle the persistence.
I'm stock on the following error when i start the server Tomcat7 and don't know how to proceed:

```
juin 23, 2013 2:13:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Access\Advanced\Wave\Gemalto\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;E:\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;E:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Cracklock\Bin;.
juin 23, 2013 2:13:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:IPS_ada' did not find a matching property.
juin 23, 2013 2:13:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
juin 23, 2013 2:13:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
juin 23, 2013 2:13:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1063 ms
juin 23, 2013 2:13:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Démarrage du service Catalina
juin 23, 2013 2:13:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
juin 23, 2013 2:13:16 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [176] milliseconds.
juin 23, 2013 2:13:17 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\Stage PFE ADA\Outils\ADA eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\IPS_ada\WEB-INF\lib\javax.el_2.2.0.v201108011116.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
juin 23, 2013 2:13:17 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\Stage PFE ADA\Outils\ADA eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\IPS_ada\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
juin 23, 2013 2:13:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
juin 23, 2013 2:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
14:14:01,375  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] ContextLoader:272 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
14:14:01,690  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] XmlWebApplicationContext:503 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Jun 23 14:14:01 WEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
14:14:01,882  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringBeans.xml]
14:14:04,431  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:177 - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/database/hibernate.properties]
14:14:04,494  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory:577 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3b1b8c1b: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,sessionFactory,baftierDAO,action]; root of factory hierarchy
14:14:04,523  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] DriverManagerDataSource:153 - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
14:14:04,938  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] Version:37 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
14:14:04,948  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] Version:41 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.0.Final}
14:14:04,954  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] Environment:224 - HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
14:14:04,955  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] Environment:342 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
14:14:05,086  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,166  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,207  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,244  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,288  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,336  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,387  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,450  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,498  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,547  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,585  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,626  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,666  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:05,700  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] DTDEntityResolver:74 - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
14:14:06,120  WARN [localhost-startStop-1] JdbcServicesImpl:169 - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'sa'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
14:14:06,130  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] Dialect:128 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
14:14:06,143  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] LobCreatorBuilder:85 - HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
14:14:06,159  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] TransactionFactoryInitiator:68 - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
14:14:06,166  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:48 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
14:14:06,672  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] SchemaExport:343 - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
14:14:06,679 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] SchemaExport:385 - HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'sa'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:500)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:251)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:589)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
14:14:06,681  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] SchemaExport:405 - HHH000230: Schema export complete
14:14:06,893  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory:434 - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3b1b8c1b: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,sessionFactory,baftierDAO,action]; root of factory hierarchy
14:14:06,894 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] ContextLoader:318 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'action' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringBeans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'baftierDAO' of bean class [ma.ada.presta.actions.Action]: Bean property 'baftierDAO' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'baftierDAO' of bean class [ma.ada.presta.actions.Action]: Bean property 'baftierDAO' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    ... 23 more
juin 23, 2013 2:14:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'action' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringBeans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'baftierDAO' of bean class [ma.ada.presta.actions.Action]: Bean property 'baftierDAO' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'baftierDAO' of bean class [ma.ada.presta.actions.Action]: Bean property 'baftierDAO' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    ... 23 more

juin 23, 2013 2:14:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
juin 23, 2013 2:14:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/IPS_ada] suite aux erreurs précédentes
juin 23, 2013 2:14:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
juin 23, 2013 2:14:07 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/IPS_ada] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
juin 23, 2013 2:14:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
juin 23, 2013 2:14:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
juin 23, 2013 2:14:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 51577 ms
```

My applicationContexte.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location">
                <value>/WEB-INF/database/hibernate.properties</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
      <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
      </bean>
        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>


            <property name="hibernateProperties">
               <props>
                         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
               </props>
            </property>
           <property name="mappingResources">
                <list>                
                  <value>/ma/ada/presta/model/hbm/Baftier.hbm.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>


        </bean>    

     <!--<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" >
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>-->

    <bean id="baftierDAO" class="ma.ada.presta.DAO.BaftierDAO" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="action" class="ma.ada.presta.actions.Action">
        <property name="baftierDAO" ref="baftierDAO" /> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My hibernate.properties is :

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


  <display-name>ada_ips</display-name>



   <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContexte.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


  <filter> 
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>


  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>




  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/view/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I need your help

Comment: Is it possible you have different properties file with `jdbc.username=sa`?

Comment: You've used different configuration to access database post web.xml

Comment: i added my web.xml to the question

Comment: no i have only one hibernate.properties with username root the username "sa" is in hibernte.properties by default in jar of hibernate the problem is that hibernate must ignore the default hibernate.properties and take mine

Answer (score 0):

try to add the following code in hibernate property

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
             <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">root</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">root</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
      </props>
 </property>
```